# Printing via cups using javax.print

Tags: java, printing

I have a file that works just fine if I use the command `lp filename`.

The file is an ESC/P file for a receipt impact printer. That has linux native CUPS drivers and all that works.

Im trying to use the `javax.print` API so that I can have a finer grained control over the printing and hopefully keep it cross-platform compatible, though Linux is the target platform.

I've tried every DocFlavor combination known to man and every type of data type (`InputStream`, `byte[]`, `Reader` etc.)

It either just ignores the `print()` command all together or just flips out a blank sheet of paper. Running `lp filename` prints it perfect, so how do I get `javax.print` to just do the functional equivalent of `lp filename`?

I'm not set on using `javax.print` I can use other "things" and might start investigating cups4J but it seems it would limit me to Linux/*nix only, which is OK for now but would rather have a cross platform solution.

I could just issue the `lp` system command on the file but, I need finer grained control. These aren't receipts we're printing, they are tickets and the tickets range from $5.00 to to thousands of dollars. Currently if we detect a printing issue, we void the transaction and if anything printed, its invalid, we don't take reprints lightly and most of the time charge to print a new copy if the customer looses his copy. Oh the reason for doing this is we're changing the POS system from Windows to Linux and the printers from direct access over serial ports to CUPS managed over USB. Here's my code that doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
try {
    // Find the default service
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;

    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    // Create the print job
    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/bart/real.escp");
    Doc docNew = new SimpleDoc(in,flavor,null);

    // Monitor print job events; for the implementation of PrintJobWatcher,
    // see Determining When a Print Job Has Finished
    PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);

    // Print it
    job.print(docNew, null);

    // Wait for the print job to be done
    pjDone.waitForDone();

    // It is now safe to close the input stream
    in.close();
} catch (PrintException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Printing from Java on linux is dicey at best.  I've taken to shelling out to the command line with an lpr command to do some of my printing.  One option might be to see if you can convert your file to a format that Java understands, like PDF and then use javax.print on it.

Comment: That's the problem there may be a linux esc/p converter but why bother when the lp command prints fine, seems like asking for trouble to go from ESC/P (that can be fed directly to the printer) ->PDF (to make Java Happy)->ESC/P(via the driver). We are generating the ESC/P files. Anyway works great with Cups4J, took about 15 minutes to implement. Guess I'll use cups4J and deal with any other OS/printing system issues when they pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I am fine with cups4j.
First get your printer.

```
try { 
        CupsClient client = new CupsClient("addressOfTheCupsServer", 631);
        List<CupsPrinter> printers = client.getPrinters();
        if (printers.size() == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Cant list Printer");
        }
        for (CupsPrinter cupsPrinter : printers) {
            if (cupsPrinter.getName().equals("NameOfPrinter")) {
                selectedPrinter = cupsPrinter;
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception ignored){
        ignored.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then create a printjob and send it to the printer

```
 PrintJob printJob = new PrintJob.Builder(inputStream).jobName("Jobname").build();
    PrintRequestResult result = selectedPrinter.print(printJob);
```

Comment: This worked for me but I tried to print a byte[] array which resulted in problematic printed symbols. I had to set the printer to pdf only through CUPS server and it worked. I wonder if I can configure that the byte array is pdf through code.